# Corda OutOfMemory Issue And ActiveMQ large message size issue

Tags: corda

I tried sending almost 5000 output states in a single transaction and I ran out of memory. I am trying to figure out how to increase memory. I tried increasing in the runnodes.bat file by teaking command

```
java -Xmx1g -jar runnodes.jar %*
```

But this doesn't seem to increase the heap size. So I tried running the following command for each node manually with memory option given -Xmx1g.

```
bash -c 'cd "/build/nodes/Notary" ; "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java" "-Dname=Notary-corda.jar" "-Dcapsule.jvm.args=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -javaagent:drivers/jolokia-jvm-1.3.7-agent.jar=port=7005,logHandlerClass=net.corda.node.JolokiaSlf4Adapter" **"-Xmx1g"** "-jar" "corda.jar" && exit'
```

This solved out of memory issue but now I started seeing ActiveMQ large message size issue

```
E 10:57:31-0600 [Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-IO-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$4@2cfd9b0a)] impl.JournalImpl.run - appendAddRecord::java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Record is too large to store 22545951 {}
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Record is too large to store 22545951
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.switchFileIfNecessary(JournalImpl.java:2915) ~[artemis-journal-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
```

Any idea?

Comment: What's in the transaction? It looks like it's around 20MB in size.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to send a transaction that is almost 20MB in size. In Corda 3 and earlier, the limit on transaction size is 10MB, and this amount is not configurable.

In Corda 4, the limit on transaction size can be configured by the network operator as one of the network parameters (see https://docs.corda.net/head/network-map.html#network-parameters). The logic for allowing a configurable limit is that otherwise, larger nodes could bully smaller nodes off the network by sending extremely large transactions that it would be infeasible for the smaller nodes to process.

Comment: Do you know where the limitation of 10MB is set? And why and how Corda came up with 10MB size?